# Add edge to matplotlib plot and give a edgecolor (no scatter)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


plt.plot(df.A,df.B,color='black',marker='o',linestyle='', markersize=5)
```

Insted of putting `black` dots, I want to put `white` dots with `black` circle/edge and adjust edge size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `markerfacecolor='white'` to your keyword arguments:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 2)), columns=list('AB'))


plt.plot(df.A,df.B,color='black',marker='o',markerfacecolor='white',linestyle='',markersize=5)
# or use mfc='white' instead
```

From the [documentation:](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot)

> kwargsLine2D properties, optional
>   kwargs are used to specify properties like a line label (for auto legends), linewidth, antialiasing, **marker face color**.
>
> **markerfacecolor or mfc**        color

where color is [one of these colors](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib-colors).

Comment: "AttributeError: PathCollection.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markerfacecolor'"